# Freeing a null pointer causes following pop up message

Tags: c++

I have some memory intensive code followed by the following statement

```
free(array1); // array1 is NULL
```

I essentially called free upon a null pointer. It was my understanding that accidentally calling free on a NULL pointer was safe. However, I got the following pop up when the free statement was executed.

*"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in app.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in app.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded."*

Does this mean free is not safe to call on NULL pointers, or is this a sign that there could be memory problems in my program?

When I uncomment the free statement, everything works normally.

Comment: Why are you using `free` in C++ and not `new/delete`?

Comment: How can an array be null :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely safe to call `free()` on a NULL pointer, *so you must have corrupted your heap earlier*.  That said, it may be worth putting a print statement in to guarantee array1 really is NULL just before the crash.  If you can't spot the error, you may have to resort to tools to help you - there are lots of questions about such heap usage verification tools.

Supporting docs: you're on Windows, but the API is the standardised with the C language: see "If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed." at http://linux.die.net/man/3/free

Of course, you should check `new`/`new[]`/`malloc`-or-`realloc` are properly paired with `delete`/`delete[]`/`realloc`-or-`free` everywhere.  There are valid reasons to be using `malloc`/`free` in C++ though - most obviously for interoperability with C code, and very occasionally for the potential performance benefits of in-place growth with `realloc`.

"When I uncomment the free statement, everything works normally." - best not to rely on that... if your program misuses the heap, it could crash at any time e.g. some runs and not others, after the tiniest seemingly unrelated change anywhere in your code, after changing a compiler flag, with innocuous input changes, or even the same executable deployed on another PC....

Comment: You might add that free() is not setting pointer to NULL (which I guess was presumed by original poster).

Comment: @PTwr: a useful comment, but not sure how relevant... OP should consider.